# Story about aliens using machine to remove and send their collective evil thoughts away to a place that, in a twist, is right in the path of Earth

Tags: story-identification, aliens

About a decade ago, I read a brief synopsis of a Sci-Fi work (may have been a Golden Age, Sci-Fi short story in an anthology on Wikipedia) of a "Utopian" alien civilization that would send their collective negative, violent, insane, evil thoughts/feelings off-world to a place that was revealed in a *Twilight Zone* like twist to be right in the path of Earth.

The story synopsis

- might have been centered on a violent criminal on trial,
- the alien civilization passes judgement to remove these tendencies.
- uses the machine that sucked the negative, dark thoughts the society had away towards the unknown in a presumably safe area (that was revealed to be directly in the path of Earth).

If I remember correctly some members of the civilization may have also objected against this practice, with some wondering where their negative tendencies went to (akin to “*mass can neither be created nor destroyed*”). Someone may have also brought up the danger to any sentient life in contact with their collective negative “aura” (it drives them insane), with the grand reveal that the planet is Earth and an explanation for human malice/ self-destruction (someone in summary may have likened it as “tossing away trash” and doubt any life was in the path).

While the details are a bit murky, I remember the twist and the basic plot idea. Alien civilization sucking their collective aggression, insanity out and sending it away as byproduct into space toward Earth (that will likely come back to haunt them later when humanity uses the discarded malice and insanity against them)

Most results I’ve found do not match the scenario (Earth remains clueless, the aliens have a Utopian civilization with no desire for violence, the grand “purifying” machine is a focus, “evil” is purged and some aliens have reservations on their actions).

Sadly I ended up mixing the story title with Asimov's *Nightfall* for some reason. Any help finding information on Sci-Fi stories with this approximate premise would be appreciated.

**TL:DR** Looking for story about alien civilization using machine to remove/ send collective negative, violent, insane, “evil” thoughts & feelings away to a place, that was revealed in a *Twilight Zone* twist, to be right in the path of Earth.

**It indeed is Harlan Ellison's "*The Beast that Shouted Love at the Heart of the World*" (The synopsis was related to research about *Neon Genesis Evangelion* episode titles)**

Comment: This sounds like Harlan Ellison's "The Beast that Shouted Love at the Heart of the World", already answered [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/239116/sci-fi-story-involving-an-insane-multi-headed-dragon-and-a-statue-found-on-a-pla/239119#239119)

Comment: Thanks for confirming Dragan's identification. I've linked this to the previous question.