# Sci-fi story about a reincarnating evil spirit that possesses someone from time to time, leading them to commit evil actions

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

IIRC, it's one of those old magazine short stories from the '50s-'70s, written by one of the greats (although I don't remember which one).

It's about an evil spirit (or a more sciency interpretation of the concept) that possesses someone from time to time leading them to commit evil actions. The story goes over several instances of this; I remember details about two:

- A guy that sprays his neighbour's milk (back when milk was delivered to your doorstep) with pesticide to poison him and his family.
- Another that takes a sub machine gun (a M3 or a Sten I think) to a concentration of people and commits a mass shooting.

Answer (score 10):

**The Beast that Shouted Love at the Heart of the World**, by Harlan Ellison.

[image: Cover of the book]

[It's a 1968 short story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beast_that_Shouted_Love_at_the_Heart_of_the_World_(short_story)) that won the Hugo Award for Best Short Story in 1969

Its narrative structure is very complicated and its plot moves through different eras, but part of it is this:

> A man, William Sterog, goes on a killing spree. He poisons two hundred
> people with an insecticide stolen from a pest control man, kills a
> hundred people on a jet flight by means of a time bomb planted in his
> mother's suitcase, and shoots 44 people in a stadium with a machine
> gun, before he is arrested.

This story should not be confused with [the book of the same title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beast_that_Shouted_Love_at_the_Heart_of_the_World) whose cover I included above and which is a collection of short stories.

Comment: If so, a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/239116/sci-fi-story-involving-an-insane-multi-headed-dragon-and-a-statue-found-on-a-pla

Comment: That must be it, thank you.

Comment: @k9898 You are welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer!